# Calculator in C should only accept float/int numbers

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, calculator

I am working on a little calculator with just basic operators. It works really well, just like I wanted it. But there is one little problem.
My program is within a loop, so the user can theoretically use it after every calculation again.
But I also want the program to distinguish between numbers of type `float` and every other element, so it only accepts floats or integers.

Here is the problem:
If I enter an alphabetic character, the problem gets confused and loops itself not properly.
You can try it out yourself when entering some random letters instead of the expected two numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    float num1, num2, result = 0;
    int menu;

    while (1)       //so that the program basically never stops
    {
        printf("--- Taschenrechner ---\n\n"
               "1. Addition\n"
               "2. Subtraktion\n"
               "3. Multiplikation\n"
               "4. Division\n"
               "5. Beenden\n"
               "Wählen Sie Ihren gewünschten Operator aus (oder auch nicht): ");
        // it is like the calculators menu, distinguishing between
        // addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and exit
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        if (menu >= 5 || menu < 1)
        {
            printf("\nDas Programm wurde beendet, schade. Bis zum nächsten Mal!");      //if the given integer is 5 or not part of the menu, the program should stop
            break;
        }
        printf("\n\nGeben Sie nun zwei Zahlen ein:\n");     //user should provide two numbers
        scanf("%f", &num1);
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%f", &num2);
        if ((isalpha(num1) || isalpha(num2)) == 0)      //if the given elements are no numbers at all, in this case part of the alphabet, the program should stop
        {
            printf("Gut!");
        } else
        {
            printf("Break");
            break;
        }
        switch (menu)
        {
        case 1:
            result = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = num1 - num2;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = num1 * num2;
            break;
        case 4:
            result = num1 / num2;
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n\nUps, da ist wohl etwas mit den Operatoren schief gelaufen. Versuchen Sie es erneut!");      //here again, if something went wrong within the switch case, program should stop
            break;
        }
        printf("\n\nPerfekt, das hat geklappt!");
        sleep(1);       //this is just for delaying the result 
        printf("\n\nIhr Ergebnis wird berechnet\nErgebnis: %.2f\n\n\n", result);
        sleep(3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I really don't know how to fix this, trying it for days now. The solution is probably really easy but I just don't get it.
A little help would be really nice. :)

And also don't mind the program being in German. I've explained some stuff as comments.

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`. That will at least tell you whether the input could be parsed. But if it fails you need to still consume the invalid input. Suggest you change the code to use `fgets` to read/consume one line of input and then `sscanf` to parse the input.

Comment: Passing a float to `isalpha` will not validate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure the user types valid input, you should verify `scanf()` successful operation and asks the user for new input in case of invalid data. `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. In case of invalid input, you should read and discard the rest of the current input line.

Note also that `if ((isalpha(num1) || isalpha(num2)) == 0)` is incorrect: it tests if `num1` or `num2` are the codes for ASCII letters. This would erroneously detect invalid input if the use types `65` or `97`...

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    float num1, num2, result = 0;
    int menu;

    while (1) {       //so that the program basically never stops
        printf("--- Taschenrechner ---\n\n"
               "1. Addition\n"
               "2. Subtraktion\n"
               "3. Multiplikation\n"
               "4. Division\n"
               "5. Beenden\n"
               "Wählen Sie Ihren gewünschten Operator aus (oder auch nicht): ");
        // it is like the calculators menu, distinguishing between
        // addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and exit

        if (scanf("%d", &menu) != 1 ||  // invalid menu entry, bail out
            menu >= 5 || menu < 1) {
            printf("\nDas Programm wurde beendet, schade. Bis zum nächsten Mal!");      //if the given integer is 5 or not part of the menu, the program should stop
            break;
        }
        for (;;) {
            printf("\n\nGeben Sie nun zwei Zahlen ein:\n");     //user should provide two numbers
            if (scanf("%f%f", &num1, &num2) == 2)
                break;
            printf("\nUngültige Eingabe\n");
            if (scanf("%*[^\n]") == EOF)    // discard the rest of the input line
                return 1;
        }
        switch (menu) {
          case 1:
            result = num1 + num2;
            break;
          case 2:
            result = num1 - num2;
            break;
          case 3:
            result = num1 * num2;
            break;
          case 4:
            result = num1 / num2;
            break;
          default:
            printf("\n\nUps, da ist wohl etwas mit den Operatoren schief gelaufen. Versuchen Sie es erneut!\n");
            //here again, if something went wrong within the switch case, program should stop
            return 1;
        }
        printf("\n\nPerfekt, das hat geklappt!");
        sleep(1);       //this is just for delaying the result 
        printf("\n\nIhr Ergebnis wird berechnet\nErgebnis: %.2f\n\n\n", result);
        sleep(3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- there are 2 reasons for `scanf()` to fail to convert the 2 floats:

  - premature end of file,
  - an offending character in the stream that cannot be the start of a number, such as `A` or `%`.
- to flush the remainder of the line entered by the user, one can use a loop:

  ```
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
      continue;
  if (c == EOF) {
      /* no more characters available from stdin: bail out */
      return 1;
  }
  ```

or one can use a `scanf()` conversion format that will read and discard all characters up to a newline:

```
  if (scanf("%*[^\n]") == EOF)    // discard the rest of the input line
      return 1;
```

here is the explanation:

- the `*` after the `%` prevents storing the converted value, no pointer is expected for the conversion specifier.
- `[...]` specifies a *scanset*, a set of characters to accept or to reject. `[abcx-z]` accepts any non-empty combination of `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `z` and any characters between `x` and `z` (`y` in the ASCII character set). `[^\n]` accepts any non-empty sequence of characters different from `\n`, hence the rest of the input line, if any.
- the character typed by the user that could not be converted along with the rest of the line will be read and discarded, leaving the newline pending.
- if no such characters are available before the newline, `scanf()` returns `0` and the newline is still pending for the next `%f` conversion;
- if the stream has reached end of file immediately, `scanf()` returns `EOF` which should cause the program to exit.

Comment: Can you please explain the expression  

if (scanf("%*[^\n]") == EOF)

? Especially the part in between scanf and EOF

Comment: @sam3004: I amended the answer with an explanation for discarding the invalid input line

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking the value returned by `scanf`.  eg: `if( scanf("%d", &menu) == 1 ) { ... }`.  If the next character of the input stream is not part of a valid integer, the above `scanf` will return 0.

In general, you should *always* check the value returned by scanf.